# Save value in PHP Session variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have an html table which contains records, comes from mysql db. Each row also contains id (PK) wrt db table record.
Now I want to save record id in **PHP Session variable**, when I click on a row.
To do this I used **onclick** property for each row & call a javascript function with record id as function parameter & it works fine but how could I save this id in **PHP Session variable** ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible because PHP is [server-side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting). However, you can use [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) for that.

Here is an ajax tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp

Answer (score 0):

To do this you probably need to use ajax. Which is where on a click event you could probably call a different php to save your values in session