# Use Jquery to get data value and supply it to a session variable

Tags: php, jquery

I need help cause I am a total newb on this.

I set up a session in my header:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['catname'] = $catname;
```

Which I retrieve in my single pages:

```
$catname = $_SESSION['catname']; 
session_destroy();
```

I have several divs, each with data type that can be used by jquery:

```
<div class="mydiv1" data-category="cat1"></div>

<div class="mydiv2" data-category="cat2></div>
```

Is it possible to use jquery on click function to get "cat1" and "cat2" from data-category and use this to supply $catname for my session variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use ajax for this.

Maybe something like:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
var catname = $("#mydiv1").attr("data-category");
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "file.php",
    data : "&catname="+catname,
    success : function(data){
         alert("Success");
    }
});
});
```

You will do the storing of session variable in the "file.php" by getting the catname.
Seems you have similar problem here: [save-value-in-php-session-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261978/save-value-in-php-session-variable)

Comment: Ty for helping. I think this is the way to go. I am using wordpress and I will be sending the catname variable to a post page. Do you think I can use the actual post link for file.php?

Comment: Or do I have to make a function in file.php which ads the catname value in the post database field. (not sure if you are familiar with wordpress but I can update a custom field using file.php)

Comment: @webmasters, I'm not so familiar with Wordpress but I did some reading. You can point the url of your ajax to "functions.php" in Wordpress then make a function inside where you will process the catname variable in any way you want. Change also the url to "functions.php/functionname" where functionname is the name of the function you created inside functions.php. Hope it helps.